# Rendered eevee is blurry

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

My Eevee render is blurry, pixelated whereas the viewpoint is totally fine. I tried different setting, increasing sampling, etc', but it seems that I'm missing something more fundamental.

I downloaded couple of files from Blender.org, used the same setting, then when I moved the camera position it all became pixelated.

Any input would be highly appreciated!
[render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKBup.png)
[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11frqNE6gFIhvQhusuBtL130OGQKBkK13/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your active camera has [Depth of Field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/depth_of_field.html) enabled and the focus is controlled by the object `camera DOF`. But for some reason, your `camera DOF` is in the nirvana. If you select it and try to grab it with <kbd>G</kbd> the location is `nan(ind)`?! Similar to this question [nanind-m-location-for-camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174807/nanind-m-location-for-camera). (Honestly, I don't know how to fix this.)

I just would delete the bad object, create a new Empty and specify it as DOF object. Move the Empty (Sphere in the screenshot) to your model. This is where the camera's focus is. The background will be blurry.

[image]

Comment: +1 for "... focus point is in the nirvana..."  :)